# How to reference an image within quotation marks in a script

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to reference an image instead of using text within the script tag in a html page. I am attempting to use an image for a button instead of text. When the button is pressed it changes to the text 'Paused' as shown below.

```
pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
```

When it is pressed again it displays the words 'Pause'.

```
pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
```

Instead I would like it to display an image I created. This code shows a section where I tried to reference the image.

```
pauseButton.innerHTML = "url(Images/pausebackground.png)";
```

Instead of displaying the image it displays 'url(Images/pausebackground.png)' in the form of text.

How can I reference the image within the quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put HTML code into `innerHTML` (as the name suggests). Use an `<img>` tag:

```
pauseButton.innerHTML = '<img src="Images/pausebackground.png">';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `innerHTML` property will change the html *inside* the element:

```
<div>
  Here is the inner html.
</div>
```

If you wish to add a image to the inner html, you could use a normal image tag, but remember, just setting the `innerHTML` will remove anything that is inside of it already.

```
pauseButton.innerHTML = '<img src="Images/pausebackground.png" />'
```

If you wish to use the image as a background of the button (which I guess you would rather do) you could either just set the image as the elements style.backgroubndImage property or rather, create a css class and add it to the button when you need (through js).

```
// Alt 1, changing the style of the element:
pauseButton.style.backgroundImage = "url(Images/pausebackground.png)";

// Alt 2, creating a css class and adding it to the element when needed:
// CSS.
.my-special-button-class {
  background-image: url(Images/pausebackground.png)
}

// JS.
pauseButton.classList.add("my-special-button-class");
```

Answer (score 0):

An image in HTML uses the `<img>` tag, which has a `src` attribute pointing to the image URL, as so:

```
<img src="Images/pausebackground.png">
```

To insert the image into the HTML, you could use `innerHTML`, but it is best to add an actual HTML element:

```
var image = document.createElement('img'); // Create the HTML element
image.setAttribute('src', 'Images/pausebackground.png'); // Set the image src
pauseButton.appendChild(image); // Place it inside the button
```

To set a different image, all you need to do is change the `src` attribute on the image tag.